# Serialize/deserialize a MQMessage

Tags: java, serialization, messaging, ibm-mq, trace

I want to serialize a MQMessage and save it to disk/database. My goal is to be able to deserialize it at a later time with all headers, named properties and contents intact.

To be clear I need something like this:

```
byte[] serialize(MQMessage m);
MQMessage deserialize(byte[] b);
```

such that when doing the following:

```
MQMessage M = deserialize(serialize(m));
```

what I get is that `M` is a "clone" of `m`.

This is required to be able, if needed, to resubmit messages for processing (in a large MQ network, applications are going to eat/lose some messages sooner or later). As such, I need to be able to deserialize a 1:1 copy of each MQMessage I want to resubmit (i.e. not just of its contents, but also its headers, properties, encoding, format, and so on...).

Unfortunately it seems that MQMessage does not implement any kind of serialization mechanism. How would you go about doing this? Is hand-crafting the serialization/deserialization code the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel.  There are already lots of free and commercial tools available to do message replay.

Here is a list of free MQ tools:
http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_tools.html

Here is a list of commercial MQ tools:
http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_tools_comm.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question was "how can I do it?", not "which tools should I use?" (that is to say, I posted a question on StackOverflow; you gave an answer that would be OK on SuperUser).

Comment: Also, since you're posting links to your website, you may wish to know that some of the links are outdated (404 and the like).